# Махинация со строками и списками

Tags: python

Всем привет.
Тут такая задачка возникла.
Пользователь вводит строку как в калькулятор: 123+500+456 не важно. И надо сделать вот что. 
Раздробить строку с помощью `input = list(input)`, и получаем ['1','2','3','+','5' ...]. И сделать так, чтобы пройтись по этому списку и соединить то, что относиться к числам, а операторы сложения(-,*,/ и т.д) оставить. Получается: ['123','+','500' ...].

 Как это реализовать или есть примерно похожий альтернативный способ решения задачи.

Comment: Похоже, вы пытаетесь изобрести токенизатор

Comment: a) регулярка должна помочь, полагаю. б) "в лоб" - массив для сравнения и сравнивать каждый символ. Только не вижу смысл тогда символы дробить.

Comment: Я не так давно в программировании на Пайтон. Не сильно понимаю о чем речь.

Comment: Мансур, я поместил решение в ответ с комментариями. С регулярными выражениями, возможно, будет побыстрее, (а может и нет) но я их не люблю:-) Да и вряд ли здесь быстродействие важно.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вот решение "в лоб".
Для тестовой строки: s='123+56+244/34-57*26'

получаем ['123', '+', '56', '+', '244', '/', '34', '-', '57', '*', '26']

```
s = input ()
# Кортеж для проверки на соответствие
mas= ('+','-','/','*')
# Финальный список
list1=[]
# переменная для накопления числа в строковом виде
s_temp=''
# Идем посимвольно по всей строке
for symbol in s:
    # Если символ оператора, то запишем в список накопленное число и оператор 
    if symbol in mas:
        list1.append(s_temp)
        list1.append(symbol)
        # "Обнулим" накопленную строку
        s_temp = ''
    # Не оператор - накапливаем строку
    else:
        s_temp += symbol
# Записываем последнюю накопленную строку
list1.append(s_temp)
print (list1)
```

Comment: Благодарю, это то что мне было нужно.

Answer (score 1):

Регулярное выражение:

```
import re


expr = '12+34 - 56 / 78 * 90'
print(re.findall('\d+|[-+*/]', expr))
```

> ```
> $ python tokenizer.py
> ['12', '+', '34', '-', '56', '/', '78', '*', '90']
> ```